# What resources exist to help SF fans meet other fans, face-to-face?

Tags: fans

Where can SF fans who want to attend informal fannish gatherings find such gatherings?

Meetup.com can be spotty, and there are lots of groups that don't have a presence there.

Comment: @Mike - there is no one answer to this question - I guess the questioner is asking for more ideas.

Comment: @Wikis - if that's the case, then this question should be closed. Stackexchange sites are for questions that *do* have answers that everyone can agree on, and can then be accepted.

Comment: @Mike - I know that is the purpose of StackExchange. However, I think (and have argued on meta) that we need more latitude with some proposals, especially this one. But that discussion should probably take place on meta...

Comment: @Mike, Wikis at Area 51 is correct, it was really a request for more ideas. I think a selection of ideas _is_ the answer. No one idea is going to work for everyone. Since the bounty is close to expiring and no new answers have been suggested I'll give the bounty to the answer I voted up.

Comment: You can always head over to chat and ask about the local events, like Comic Con, and ask if anybody from your region will be attending and perhaps wants to meet up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start your own group and advertise on [Upcoming](http://upcoming.org), [Craigslist](http://craigslist.org), and your local bookstore. Reach out to nearby users on [GoodReads](http://goodreads.com). If you want to game, try [NearbyGamers](http://nearbygamers.net). Ask around at your closest [hacker space](http://hackerspaces.org/wiki/List_of_Hacker_Spaces). I suggest pick a coffee shop (or some place you don't mind hanging out for a couple hours), advertise a new group, and see who shows up.

Answer (score 11):

### Conventions!

I've been going to SF conventions since the 1970s, and I always have a great time. Pretty much anywhere you are in the world, there'll be a SF Con sometime this year that's not too far away.

Here are a few Con lists:

- [Locus Online: Convention Listings](http://www.locusmag.com/Resources/Conventions.html)
- [List of Upcoming Sci-Fi Cons](http://www.upcomingcons.com/science-fiction-conventions)
- [Fanboy's Convention list](http://www.fanboyslist.com)

The next one I'm attending: [Renovation](http://www.renovationsf.org), the 69<sup>th</sup> annual World Science Fiction Convention—aka WorldCon (Reno NV, August 17-21). If you can make it to only one, *that's* the one to make it to.

Comment: like the bi-mon-sci-fi-con

Comment: I think the questioner means smaller, local meetups that meet more frequently.

Answer (score 7):

In general, trying to find which club sponsors the local science fiction convention is a good way to meet fannish types, even if you are not into going to conventions.

In Denver, for instance, the Denver Area Science Fiction Association ([DASFA](http://www.dasfa.org/)) sponsors MileHiCon.  (Disclaimer:  I'm the editor of the newsletter for DASFA).  We have actually hooked up the club to meetup as well, although most people who attend don't seem to RSVP (meetup says 3 people coming, 15-30 show up.)

Answer (score 1):

You can also add your email address (and / or website) to your profile on this site.